# Design Patterns in Go

Tags: go

How would one go about implementing Observer, Strategy and an MVC file structure in Go?

Is there a book or website that teaches how to implement these three and hopefully most of the "gang-of-four" design patterns?

Comment: GoF design patterns are common solutions to problems in object-oriented programming.  Some people, like functional programmers, would say that these are band aids on flaws in the OOP idiom.  Do you need them in Go?  https://flaviocopes.com/golang-is-go-object-oriented/

Comment: I understand from where you come from, I think each of us went through the GoF indoctrination. Then a revival of Functional Programming showed that patterns (and OO) are highly overrated. And as other answers mention, Go is not a language adapted to classic OO. The best I can suggest is to go through documentation such as A tour of Go, Effective Go, Go by Example and walk enough in Go shoes to become disintoxicated :-) It takes time, it is worth it. Embrace Go, do not try to bend Go to what Go is not.

Comment: @duffymo marco-m: Alright. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, design patterns are not programming paradigm specific. MVC, Observer and Strategy can be implemented in any programming paradigm. OOP was itself a "design pattern" and was implemented in C and others waay before C++ and Java came along.

Comment: As suggested by other, design patterns are not an absolute necessity in go, and cant be exactly emulated as it is not purely an OOP language. But if you are still looking for references, this one might help: https://github.com/ashwinshirva/api/tree/master/dp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go doesn't do OOP, so technically GoF design patterns look weird.

I have seen some repos that try to emulate those in a way (a quick search got me https://github.com/bvwells/go-patterns and https://github.com/tmrts/go-patterns). I have tried before using factory pattern on some db code and now I am doing something that is MVC-like, but it doesn't feel totally idiomatic.

You can try doing these for fun or just to learn, however don't start with the file structure and stuff when you code.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thank you.